# Template friendship

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I'm trying to access protected variables of a template class with different template parameters. A friend declaration with template parameters is giving the following error:

*multiple template parameter lists are not allowed*

My code is

```
template<class O_, class P_> 
class MyClass {
    //multiple template parameter lists are not allowed
    template<class R_> friend class MyClass<R_, P_> 
    //syntax error: template<
    friend template<class R_> class MyClass<R_, P_> 

public:
    template<class R_>
    ACopyConstructor(MyClass<R_, P_> &myclass) :
       SomeVariable(myclass.SomeVariable)
    { }

protected:
    O_ SomeVariable;
};
```

If I remove the protection and friend declaration it works.

Comment: MyClass is a friend of it self?!!

Comment: MyClass<OtherClass, int> is not the same class as MyClass<AnotherClass, int> therefore, it cannot access to its protected variables.

Comment: AraK there's no `MyClass` as such.

Comment: friend template<class R_> class MyClass<R_, P_> 

errrr
R_ is not known there as a start IMHO

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding the question :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the standard: 14.5.3/9 [temp.friend], "A friend template shall not be declared partial specializations.", so you can only 'befriend' all instantiations of a class template or specific full specializations.

In your case, as you want to be friends with instantiations with one free template parameter, you need to declare the class template as a friend.

e.g.

```
template< class A, class B > friend class MyClass;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to be working, effectively declaring all MyClass types to be friend with each other.

```
template<class O_, class P_> 
class MyClass {
    template<class R_, class P_> friend class MyClass;

public:
    template<class R_>
    ACopyConstructor(MyClass<R_, P_> &myclass) :
       SomeVariable(myclass.SomeVariable)
    { }

protected:
    O_ SomeVariable;
};
```