# Partial specialization and friendship

Tags: c++, templates, friend, partial-specialization

Suppose you have class A like this:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class A;
```

And class B like this:

```
template <typename T>
class B;
```

And now you want both classes be friends when T is the same type, is this possible?

So for example `A<int, long>` is friends with `B<int>` while `B<int>` is friends with `A<int, U>` where `U` can be any type.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be allowed.  Can you confirm whether [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1458897/16287) answers your question?