# Why does the Standard prohibit friend declarations of partial specializations?

Tags: c++, friend, template-specialization

The C++ standard prohibits friend declarations of partial specializations. (§14.5.3/8):

> Friend declarations shall not declare partial specializations. [Example:

```
template<class T> class A { };
class X {
    template <class T> friend class A<T*>;   //error
};
```

> --end example]

Other questions, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1458752/1362568), 
have received answers that invoke this prohibition, but I would like to know the
rationale. I don't see it and can't find it with my favourite search engine. I 
can find however that it goes right back to the C++98 standard, so presumably 
the rationale is quite basic and clear. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: How is this "not constructive"?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: rough guess: it kind of asks for possible opinions

Comment: @PlasmaHH unless answered by someone who actually knows the reason (like most questions) :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a reference but I suspect that this is because it would result in the partial specialization being declared in the scope of the friend-declaring class rather than the scope of the template in question, and rather than creating a bunch of rules to force the friend declaration to result in the specialization being in the correct scope, they simply prohibit it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is speculative. There must be a definitive answer and people who know it, so I'll hold out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some undirect explanation:
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html

> A final implementation detail comes up with partial specializations:
>   how does the compiler pick which specialization to use if there are a
>   combination of completely generic types, some partial specializations,
>   and maybe even some full specializations? The general rule of thumb is
>   that the compiler will pick the most specific template
>   specialization--the most specific template specialization is the one
>   whose template arguments would be accepted by the other template
>   declarations, but which would not accept all possible arguments that
>   other templates with the same name would accept.

I infer that maybe it is not permitted to prevent any ambiguity in the determination of specialization type.

Comment: Can you give an example where it would (if allowed) cause the picking of a specialization to be ambiguous?

Comment: @faith_k, Thanks for your answer, but it is speculative. There must be a definitive answer and people who know it, so I'll hold out.

Comment: I don't buy this at all. Although the resolution rules may be complex, they still decide on a particular case. And the general "friend template" specifier actually makes all specializations friends as well. Why couldn't the partial-specialization friend specifier simply apply to all specializations (including instantiations) which matched the specified pattern?