# friend template struct declaration with overloads

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, friend

Considering the following snippet:

```
namespace nr {

  template <class ...> using void_t = void;

  template <typename T, typename = void> struct type_id {
    static int const value = 0;
  };
  template <typename T> struct type_id<T, void_t<decltype(T::type_id)>> {
    static int const value = T::type_id;
  };

}
```

Now I want to make the overload be able to access a private `type_id` static field. I can not find the correct syntax or whether it is even possible. My attempt below gives `0` instead of the exected `1`. You do get `1` if you declare the `type_id = 1` member public.

```
class Foo {
  template <typename T, typename> friend struct nr::type_id;
  static const int type_id = 1;
};

int main() {
  std::cout << nr::type_id<Foo>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567212/why-does-the-standard-prohibit-friend-declarations-of-partial-specializations) may interest you. Ps your code declares no overloads just specializations.

Comment: The results are certainly not consistent: [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) yields a compile-time error (no access to `private` variable), [clang](http://clang.llvm.org) prints `1`, and [icc](https://software.intel.com/en-us/c-compilers/ipsxe) prints `0`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Oh boy. I tested it with MSVC 2015 (as described above, it yields `0`). Thanks for checking, interesting to see this varying behaviour.

Comment: @W.F. Thanks for the link. So this is not actually allowed by the standard

Comment: From the syntax I'd think you are making the primary a `friend` anyway rather than any [partial] specialization. Making the specialization  a `friend` would be something like `template <typename T> friend struct nr::type_id<T, void>` (I don't know off-hand whether this is legal or not).

Comment: Just another data point: [EDG's frontend](http://edg.com/c) produces `1` (it took a moment because I got a demo version which doesn't have standard library). This is interesting because I thought Intel's compiler users either the EDG or the clang frontend...

Comment: There are two separate problems here: 1) if you declare a template class friend of some class do you really want to declare all of specialisations of that template to be a friend of your class - I believe the answer is no 2) should there be a way to declare which of the specializations should be a friend of that class - I'm not so sure about this one but I guess this might cause a problem with compiler implementation, it's actually a good candidate for a question I guess, because I'm not sure if the answers of the question provided in my first comment fully exhaust a problem

Comment: @W.F. That answer isn't relevant. OP is not befriending a partial specialization or anything.

Comment: GCC is definitely broken - this is shouldn't cause a hard error.

Comment: @DietmarKühl No, that `friend` friends all specializations, including partial/explicit specializations. See https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.friend#3

Comment: [Workaround](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae7fd634abac1ba0).

Comment: @T.C. Interesting, would you mind elaborating on how this works? I do not understand why the first overload `type_id_impl(...)` is needed.

Comment: Fallback for when `T::type_id` isn't valid.

Comment: And `...` is just a valid function parameter signature that the compiler can fall back to when passing 0 as an argument? (My wording might not be correct but I hope you get what I mean)

Comment: @NiklasR : `type_id_impl(...)` is just a regular [variadic function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments).

Comment: Just found the note about the use with SFINAE in the [cppreference Variadic arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) docs. "In the C programming language, at least one named parameter must appear before the ellipsis parameter, so printz(...); is not valid. In C++, this form is allowed even though the arguments passed to such function are not accessible, and is commonly used as the fallback overload in SFINAE, exploiting the lowest priority of the ellipsis conversion in overload resolution."

Comment: @T.C. while not an answer to the question, it is a solution to my problem. Thanks! :) I hope it's OK I mention you in the source [here](https://github.com/NiklasRosenstein/cpp-nr_type_id/blob/a4d606b41e8df737fe6fcc9f902e6c560385b826/include/nr/type_id.hpp#L27-L35)

Comment: Updated link to source https://github.com/NiklasRosenstein/cpp-nr_type_id/blob/d2b6bf59ecc89a1f2d701f304ba28356c2c26563/include/nr/type_id.hpp#L32-L41