# template friend class with more template parameters

Tags: c++

I have a class template Obj1 with three template parameters

```
template < class A, class B, class C >
class Obj1
{
      // some implementation
};
```

and the second class template Obj2 with two template parameters,

```
 template < class A, class B >
    class Obj2
    {
          // some implementation
    };
```

so my problem is the following:

I want to make the class Obj1 to be the friend of class Obj2, with the first two template parameters with the same value, but I do not know the exact syntax how to write it,
At first i tryed this way

```
template < class A, class B>
class Obj2
{
    template< class C>
    friend class Obj1<A,B,C>;
};
```

but it did not compile, so pleas help me if you can.

Comment: Is it feasible to define `Obj1` as a nested class, `template<typename A, typename B, typename C> using Obj1 = Obj1Parent<A,B>::Impl<C>;` and then `friend class Obj1Parent<A,B>;` ?  Since `Obj1<A,B,C>` is a member type of `Obj1Parent<A,B>`, it will gain access from such a friend declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1458897/2436175
"You can only 'befriend' all instantiations of a class template or specific full specializations."

So, this is what is allowed:

```
template < class A, class B, class C >
class Obj1
{
      // some implementation
};

template < class A, class B>
class Obj2
{
    public:
    template <class C, class D, class E> friend class Obj1; ///All instances
};

template < class A, class B>
class Obj3
{
    public:
    friend class Obj1<A,B,int>; ///One specific instantiation, possibly depending from your own templated parameters
    friend class Obj1<A,B,A>; ///One specific instantiation, possibly depending from your own templated parameters
    friend class Obj1<char,float,int>; ///One specific instantiation, possibly depending from your own templated parameters
};
```